# TeamCity is failing to checkout github repository

Tags: github, teamcity

I'm having following errors from TeamCity when it updates working directory.

I'm using TeamCity 8.1.3 and checking out github repository on agent.
Looks like it happened all of a sudden. This was working yesterday.

I'm not sure how I can investigate this issue... Could someone help me?

```
[19:11:33]Checking for changes
[19:11:34]Failed to register agent parameters for: class jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildFiles.RecentlyFailedTestsFileWriter. Error: Permission denied
[19:11:34]Failed to register agent parameters for: class jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildFiles.ChangedFilesListFileWriter. Error: Permission denied
[19:11:34]Failed to register agent parameters for: class jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildFiles.RunnerParametersFileWriter. Error: Permission denied
[19:11:34]Failed to register agent parameters for: class jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildFiles.BuildParametersFileWriter. Error: Permission denied
[19:11:34]Failed to register agent parameters for: class jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildFiles.ConfigurationParametersFileWriter. Error: Permission denied
[19:11:34]Failed to publish build.start.properties.gz file. /Users/iosdevelopment/Documents/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/build.start.properties.gz (Permission denied)
[19:11:34]Clearing temporary directory: /Users/iosdevelopment/Documents/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp
[19:11:34]Failed to delete empty directory: /Users/iosdevelopment/Documents/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp
[19:11:34]Checkout directory: /Users/iosdevelopment/Documents/buildAgent/work/ios_build_dir
[19:11:34]Updating sources: agent side checkout
[19:11:34][Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
[19:11:34][Updating sources] Cleaning /Users/iosdevelopment/Documents/buildAgent/work/ios_build_dir
[19:11:34][Updating sources] Using vcs information from server. Reason: no revision information for buildtype iPhone_CI and checkout directory /Users/iosdevelopment/Documents/buildAgent/work/ios_build_dir on agent
[19:11:34][Updating sources] VCS Root: git@github.com:taichino/iOS.git
[19:11:34][Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: Permission denied
[19:11:34]Publishing artifacts
[19:11:34]Failed to generate coverage report, error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/iosdevelopment/Documents/buildAgent/work/ios_build_dir/coverage.ic file does not exist
[19:11:34]Failed to publish build.finish.properties.gz file. /Users/iosdevelopment/Documents/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/build.finish.properties.gz (Permission denied)
[19:11:34]Build failed to start. Artifacts will not be published for this build
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an issue with access to github - more like a localised permissions issue.  Can you login to the agent as the user running the agent, and verify local permissions?  At first glance it looks like the agent service can't write to the file system.

Comment: Ummm. I can't find any issues around file permissions. The working directory is created by teamcity and the permission of the directory is 744 which seems correct. I also confirmed the process owner is same as working directory's owner...

Is there any possibility to get Permission denied?

Answer (score 3):

I meet this similar issue, it is because of permission restriction.
I `chmod -R 777` for the entire Teamcity installation, it works.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It might because you run teamcity agent under root (or other users) before, chmod -R 777 should solve the problem, but before that, you can do a "ll" on your agent's install dir, especially the ~/yourAgent/temp folder, make sure it is not owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to check out on the server, ran the build and once it finished successfully I switched back to checkout on the agent, and it worked!